# Angular 2 route param changes, but component doesn't reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, angular2-routing

So, basically I need to reload my component after `id` of url parameter was changed. This is my **player.component.ts**:

```
import {Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit} from '@angular/core';
import {ActivatedRoute, Router} from '@angular/router';
declare var jQuery: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'video-player',
  templateUrl: './player.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./player.component.less']
})

export class VideoPlayerComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  playerTop: number;
  currentVideoId: number;

  constructor(
    private _route: ActivatedRoute,
    private _router: Router
  ) {

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this._route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.currentVideoId = +params['id'];
      console.log( this.currentVideoId );
      this._router.navigate(['/video', this.currentVideoId]);
    });
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    if (this.videoPageParams(this.currentVideoId)) {
      console.log( "afterViewInit" );
      let params = this.videoPageParams(this.currentVideoId);
      let fakeVideoItemsCount = Math.floor(params.containerWidth / params.videoItemWidth);
      this.insertFakeVideoItems( this.currentVideoId, fakeVideoItemsCount);
      this.changePlayerPosition( params.videoItemTop );
    }

  }

  videoPageParams( id ): any {
    let videoItemTop = jQuery(`.videoItem[data-id="${id}"]`).position().top;
    let videoItemWidth = jQuery('.videoItem').width();
    let containerWidth = jQuery('.listWrapper').width();
    return {
      videoItemTop,
      videoItemWidth,
      containerWidth
    };
  }

  changePlayerPosition( videoItemTop ): void {
    this.playerTop = videoItemTop;
  }

  insertFakeVideoItems( id, fakeVideoItemsCount ): void {
    let fakeVideoItemHTML = `<div class="videoItem fake"></div>`;
    let html5playerHeight = jQuery('#html5player').height();
    let videoItemIndex = jQuery(`.videoItem[data-id="${id}"]`).index() + 1;
    let videoItemInsertAfterIndex;
    let videoItemRow = Math.ceil(videoItemIndex / fakeVideoItemsCount);
    let videoItemRowBefore = videoItemRow - 1;
    if ( videoItemIndex <= 4 ) {
      videoItemInsertAfterIndex = 0;
    } else {
      videoItemInsertAfterIndex = (videoItemRowBefore * fakeVideoItemsCount);
    }
    let videoItemInsertAfter = jQuery('.videoItem').eq(videoItemInsertAfterIndex);

    for ( let i = 0; i < fakeVideoItemsCount; i++ ) {
      $(fakeVideoItemHTML).insertBefore(videoItemInsertAfter);
    }
    jQuery(`.videoItem.fake`).css('height', html5playerHeight);

  }

}
```

**player.component.html**:

```
<video
    class="video"
    preload="auto"
    [attr.data-id]="currentVideoId"
    src="">
</video>

<videos-list></videos-list>
```

**videoList.component.html**

```
<div class="videoItem" *ngFor="let video of videos" [attr.data-id]="video.id">
    <a [routerLink]="['/video', video.id]">
        <img [src]='video.thumbnail' alt="1">
    </a>
</div>
```

So when I click `<a [routerLink]="['/video', video.id]">` in **videoList.component.html** it changes route to /video/10 for example, but the part from **player.component.ts** which manipulates the DOM doesn't fire again - **DOM manipulation doesn't update**.

I tried to manually navigate to route via `this._router.navigate(['/video', this.currentVideoId]);` but somehow it doesn't work.

**QUESTION**
Is there any way to run functions that manipulate DOM each time route param changes in the same URL?

Comment: Could u share ur code where u are reading routeParams?

Comment: @Smit what do you mean by ``reading``? ``this._route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.currentVideoId = +params['id'];
      console.log( this.currentVideoId );
      this._router.navigate(['/video', this.currentVideoId]);
    });`` this part is where I read route param

Comment: Why are you rerouting? `this._router.navigate(['/video', this.currentVideoId]); `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DOM will not update because ngOnInit is only fired once, so it will not update even if you try to "renavigate" back to the parent from the child, since the parent haven't been removed from the DOM at any point.

One option to solve this, is that you could use a `Subject`, that when the routing is happening, let's send the chosen video id to parent, which subscribes to the change and does whatever you tell it to do, meaning calling functions that will update the DOM, so probably what you want re-executed is the inside `ngOnInit` and `ngAfterViewInit`

You mentioned that you had tried using

```
this._router.navigate(['/video', this.currentVideoId])
```

so let's look at that. Probably have some click event that fires a function. Let's say it looks like the following, we'll just add the subject in the play

```
navigate(id) {
  VideoPlayerComponent.doUpdate.next(id)
  this._router.navigate(['/video', this.currentVideoId])
}
```

Let's declare the `Subject` in your parent, and subscribe to the changes:

```
public static doUpdate: Subject<any> = new Subject();
```

and in the constructor let's subscribe to the changes...

```
constructor(...) {
    VideoPlayerComponent.doUpdate.subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res) // you have your id here
        // re-fire whatever functions you need to update the DOM
    });
}
```